# Member Self Service

Tags: civimember, extension, joomla

I would like members to be able to log into our website and be able to see the relationships that are on their organization record so that they can let us know who is still there and who needs to be added. We have our relationships set up as Primary, Employer of, and Volunteer. We know there are limits with the way that our relationships are currently set up, but I was wondering if there is an extension we could look into or other ways to allow Primary Contact members to see. Thanks for any ideas.

Edit: we use Joomla

Comment: The Dashboard should let a contact see their related contacts. and this may give you the other feature you need  https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions - or this but have never used https://github.com/agiliway/com.agiliway.custompermission

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I am going through these now. Really appreciate you taking time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

We've addressed this need by using AlterReports on our website, Brandy. Feel free to DM me, and I'd be happy to provide additional details.
We use AlterReports for all sorts of views (event lists, rosters for event organizers, My Family list - the list goes on and on) as it has an amazing flexibility in terms of what you display and how. Cannot imagine running a complex Joomla website without it. You'll need some SQL knowledge, but I can share the query we built for the relationship list if you'd like.
Then, we use Seblod for updating data (similar to what Webform does on Drupal). The combo of Seblod and AlterReports enables us to extend the CiviCRM functionality in unexpected ways. (E.g., AlterReports displays the My Family list, and a Seblod form allows for new relationships to be added, and existing ones updated or removed.)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Exchange, Brandy. In case you are using Drupal as CiviCRM's CMS you could probably have a look at the module"CiviCRM Entity" which provides enhanced integration with Drupal.

You should be able to find some documentation about this and Skvare has recently published some [training videos / blog posts](https://civicrm.org/blog/genadellett/training-series-civicrm-entity-30-0).

Obviously you could also built something using CiviCRM's API but that will likely require some development work in your CMS and/or CiviCRM.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know if this is available for Joomla?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I am no Joomla Expert so I cannot tell if there is an equivalent for Joomla. Maybe someone else here can?

Comment: Thank you Fabian. I really appreciate you responding.